# Извлечь проект из Solution, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Имеется Solution, в котором хранится огромное количество проектов. У каждого проекта имеются зависимости от других проектов.

Можно ли сделать копию одного проекта, так чтобы скопировались проекты от которых он зависим?

Или вырезать из Solution все ненужные проекты на основе зависимостей того проекта, который меня интересует?

Короче говоря оставить в Solution только те проекты, которые необходимы для данного проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Правой по твоему нужному проекту - зависимости сборки - зависимости проектов.

Там будут отображаться зависимости проектов.

Comment: Это я знаю. Мне просто вручную все эти проекты копировать и переносить в другую папку в лом. Потом приходиться создавать новый Solution и там подключать эти проекты.
Хотелось бы автоматом все нужное вытащить в новый Solution